# What datatype to use in C# class?

Tags: c#

In school, for a C# course, they gave us a very mystical assignment. There is the following code in `Main()` and we have to write the class `Group`.

```
Group group = new Group(3);
group["wholenumber"] = 123;
group["decimalnumber"] = 456.78;
group["text"] = "Hello world!";

double sum = (double)(int)group["wholenumber"] + (double)group["decimalnumber"];
Console.WriteLine("Sum of numbers is {0}", sum);
```

Does that make any sense? I thought you cant use strings as index? I would understand if there was variable names as index, so they could pass for finals, but now I don't get it. I tried to use Google and found dictionaries which are like arrays and can use a string as an index, but all values are different - first is int, second double and last is string, so dictionary won't work.

At the moment we are talking about static classes, constants, destructors and indexers

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Dictionary<string,object>` will work

Comment: BTW, `group` is a keyword in C#. You should avoid naming your variables `group`. Use another name instead.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx

Comment: Thanks. Well, it is actually not called group, I just swiftly translated it as group from Finnish.

Comment: As to the vote to close: there is nothing wrong with a homework question, especially if it is a *good* question.

Comment: It also is not hiding the fact and the OP is not trying to make us do his work - he asks for some clarification. Totally ok with me ;)

Comment: @HighCore `group` is a contextual keyword, not a reserved word, so it's not problematic at all to use it as an identifier name.

Comment: @Servy you're right. Still, I find it odd to call a class like that.

Answer (score 3):

Since you mention that you are currently talking about indexers, this is exactly what you need to implement for your `Group` class (assuming that the code in `main` is fixed and you need to make a class work for that code).

According to [MSDN: Indexers (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx):

> Indexers do not have to be indexed by an integer value; it is up to you how to define the specific look-up mechanism.

So in this case, you could have code like:

```
public class Group
{
    public object this[string s]
    {
        get
        {
            //return something based on "s"
        }
        set
        {
            //set something based on "s"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> but all values are different - first is int, second double and last is
>   string, so dictionary  wont work.

Actually it will as System.object is a common base class. THis is why all retrievals from the Group have a cast. Not that this Group "class" makes any logical sense - noone would write a separate class for this, everyone I know would jst write:

```
var group = new Dictionary<string,object> (3);
```

Note that group is a terrible variable name due to being a keyword.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` as some guys said, but you could inherit from it, for sample:

```
public class Group : Dictionary<string, object>
{
}
```

And use like a dictionary:

```
Group g = new Group();
g.Add("wholenumber", 123);
g.Add("decimalnumber", 456.78);
g.Add("text", "Hello world!");
```

the problem to read is the value is an `object`, and you need to cast it to right type.